# Symfony2 and RabbitMqBundle. symfony event dispatcher, won't load listeners

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, rabbitmq

I need dispatch event in symfony event dispatcher while I'm in RabbitMqBundle Consumer.
Problem is that in consumer is not event dispatcher loaded properly and have no loaded listeners.

**Update:** I tried load listeners manually, but I found that Doctrine does not have its own listeners loaded too and so persisting entity with column type object fails. (Doctrine does not serialize object before updating column)

**Solution:** I had error inside entity. I had second newly added and forgotten column with object. Listeners did not load, because they was set to load on kernel.request event. But that never happened inside Consumer.

Thanks for not helping.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried load listeners manually, but I found that Doctrine does not have its own listeners loaded too and so persisting entity with column type object fails. (Doctrine does not serialize object before updating column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solution**: I had error inside entity. I had second newly added and
>   forgotten column with object. Listeners did not load, because they was
>   set to load on kernel.request event. But that never happened inside
>   Consumer.